# PHP's cURL suddenly failing to get an IP address, is file_get_contents a good replacement?

Tags: php, dns

We have a page on our site that uses cURL to get XML data from a remote domain. A few days ago it randomly started failing (perhaps 1/3 of requests fail). After debugging with our host and with the remote site's operators, we found that the curl error is 'name lookup timed out', indicating a DNS problem. Our `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` was set to 5. When I changed that to 30, it worked every time.

But this is a live page, I can't have visitors hanging for 30 seconds while waiting for a response. Plus, the increased timeout doesn't answer the question of why this started failing in the first place. The system had been in place for years prior and the 5 second timeout was always fine.

Furthermore I found that if I do a `dns_get_record()`, it works every time and I quickly get a valid IP address. So I modified the script to first do a `dns_get_record()`, then I cURL to the IP it returns, which gets around the name lookup on cURL's end. It works fine but it's silly.

So first question, does anyone have any suggestions as to how or why the cURL may be failing. Our host and the remote site's host both agree that it's a DNS server somewhere, but neither agrees on who's DNS server is responsible, because both say that their own servers are good, and our host says they can ping the remote domain without a problem.

Second question, is `file_get_contents()` a sufficient replacement for `dns_get_record()` + cURL? Or should I stick with `dns_get_record()` + cURL instead?

Comment: If it is deliberately set the remote server then you have no control over the failing even if you switch it to file_get_contents. Are you calling the remote server much faster than how you should be calling it normally?

Comment: @mauris No, it's just one request each time this page is hit. It's a popular page so it may be visited frequently, but each of those visits would be separate. Also note that dns_get_record() always succeeds, so maybe it works differently than cURL to get the IP address? And if so, maybe file_get_contents() works similarly?

Comment: if the server needs more time, either upgrade the remote server to make it faster, or use AJAX

Comment: @mauris yes but I think there's more to this than just the DNS server needing more time. The fails started happening suddenly, it's not like it was a gradual build implying a build in traffic that over time overloaded the server. Maybe something bad happened on the DNS server, but the question still remains - which server, and what happened to it? The other odd thing is that dns_get_record() has no problem with timing out, it returns an IP address almost instantly. It's only cURL that now needs extra time.

Comment: Maybe an easy and quick fix could be to write the dns settings of the remote domain in the hosts file of the server, this would work only if you're sure that the ip address of the remote domain will not change.

Comment: @Phenix Thanks, actually easier than that would be to just cURL to the IP address instead of the domain name. As you said that relies on the IP remaining the same, which is why we're doing the dns_get_record() first, grabbing a valid IP, and cURL to that IP instead.

Answer (score 3):

Under the hood, both `curl_exec` and `file_get_contents` perform nearly identical operations; they both use `libresolv` to:

1. connect to a name server
2. issue a dns request
3. process the dns response

To further debug this, you can use [`curl_getinfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) to get detailed statistics about your requests; you can use this to get an idea of how long each part took using:

- CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME
- CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME
- CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME
- ...